# Cannot test redirects when unit testing Laravel 5

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

Here is my test code:

```
public function testRegistrationFailsIfNameIsEmpty()
{
    $this->flushSession();
    $response = $this->call('POST', '/signup', ['fullname' => '']);
    $this->assertSessionHasErrors('fullname'); // Passes, expected
    $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirection()); // Passes, expected
    $this->assertRedirectedTo('/signup'); // Fails, unexpected.
}
```

When I call that method, it's validating the input, and if the validation fails, it redirects me back to `/signup` to show the validation errors. I've manually tested this in the browser, and it works as expected.

However, when I run the above unit test, the last assertion fails, and it thinks I've been redirected to just `/` rather than `/signup`.

I have no idea why it's doing this. If I test that a redirect happened at all, the test passes because a redirect *does* happen, it just thinks the redirect is to `/` instead of `/signup`.

I've disabled all middleware so I know it's not something like guest middleware thinking I'm logged in when I'm not.

EDIT: Test Results:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) RegistrationTest::testRegistrationFailsIfNameIsEmpty
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.

--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/signup'
+'http://localhost'
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility to debug your code, otherwise i would recommend to install such an environment, it will be useful many many times.

Comment: How do you test POST method in the browser? are you sure you did not test GET?

Answer (score 18):

Using request()->validate() will return you to the calling url if validation fails. When running unit tests, there is no calling page so you will be directed to home.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

> if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error
>   response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a
>   traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated

So you either need to test that your redirect is to home, or fudge the calling url. Though then you're just testing the validator rather than your code, which doesn't really add anything:

```
session()->setPreviousUrl('/calling/url');
```

https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/testing-the-redirect-url-in-laravel

Edit:
Actually, this can be useful when the test expects the redirect to go to a route with a named parameter.

Edit for Laravel 5.8:

The test should be called with:

```
$this->from('/calling/url')
    ->get('/some/route')
    ->assertRedirect('/somewhere/else');
```

Comment: Marvellous. Before this advise I was using `->withSession(['_previous' => ['url' => 'https://google.com']])`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when testing a Laravel app. It seems that when you use $this->call in the test and then your controller uses something like **Redirect::back()**, the redirect is sent to '/'. I believe this is because you weren't on any page when you made "$this->call" so the application is unsure where to redirect you, unless you are explicit about the redirect in the controller, i.e. redirect('somePage').

However when doing something like $this->actingAs($user)->visit('somePage')->press('someButton'), you are correctly sent back to the expected page when using Redirect::back(). Likely because the app knows what page you started on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set ->from(route('RouteName')) in order to make sure the redirection assertion is properly set

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to print Response object from controller with dd() when unit testing this single test. This will show you where exactly the redirect is made. Unit test engine just parses the Response object and I believe the problem is in the code rather in the Unit test.

Comment: I did, the location is definitely pointing back to the root, so the test is apprarently working as intended, but now the question is why the redirect is going back home in the test environment, while in the browser (local) it is going to where it should. I've inspected the request traffic in the browser, and there is no intermediary redirect home and then back to /signup, so I'm not sure why it's behaving the way it is.

Also, there are no error logs that indicating that a 500 is being thrown and for some reason redirecting back home.

Comment: How does your RedirectResponse look like when you dd() it in the controller prior return? It should show the targetUrl and statusCode which tell you where it was redirected. This help you understand where to start looking what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the test hitting the redirect function in controller
you can put a die in function and find-out where is the error
It should be an issue in method.
then check it actually goes in to the redirect part

Answer (score 0):

for example you want to test a request validation failure. And for example it suppose to  redirect your user to a previous url with validation failed exception and some messages. Say, you want to update a customer name.

```
    // --- making a post request ----
    $name = 'a new name that is too long';
    $route = route('customer.update');

    $response = $this
        ->withSession(['_previous' => ['url' => 'https://google.com']])
        ->call('POST', $route, [
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'name' => $name,
    ]);


    // --- unit test assertions ----
    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertRedirect('https://google.com');

    $message  = __('@lang_file.some error message text here.');
    $expected = [
        'default' => ['' => [$message]]
    ];
    $actual   = session_errors()->getBags();
    $actual   = json_encode($actual);
    $actual   = json_decode($actual, true);
    $this->assertSame($expected, $actual);
```

a function that return session errors:

```
function session_errors(): ViewErrorBag
{
  $key    = config('session.keys.errors');
  $errors = session()->get($key, app(ViewErrorBag::class));

  return $errors;
 }
```